# List of variables(XML) in combo box C#

Tags: c#, xml

I don't know how to get my variables into a combo box. I've done some research, it seems like a list to store these in is a perfect container for the elements, but getting the list to work is a different story.

Anyway, here's the code I'm using :

```
 private List<string> HNames = new List<string>();
// ^ This is stored above  `InitializeComponent();`

 void LoadXML()
{
    string path = "Mods//handling4.meta";
                var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
                var items = doc.Descendants("HandlingData").Elements("Item");
                var query = from x in items

                            select new
                            {
                                HandlingName = (string)x.Element("handlingName"),
                                HandlingType = (string)x.Element("HandlingType"),
                                Mass = (decimal?)x.Element("fMass").Attribute("value"),
                                InitialDragCoeff = (decimal?)x.Element("fInitialDragCoeff").Attribute("value"),
                                PercentSubmerged = (decimal?)x.Element("fPercentSubmerged").Attribute("value"),
                                DriveBiasFront = (decimal?)x.Element("fDriveBiasFront").Attribute("value"),
                                InitialDriveGears = x.Element("nInitialDriveGears").Attribute("value"),
                                InitialDriveForce = (decimal?)x.Element("fInitialDriveForce").Attribute("value"),
                                DriveInertia = (decimal?)x.Element("fDriveInertia").Attribute("value")
                                };
foreach(var item in query)
            {
                HNames.Add(item.HandlingName);
            }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             comboBox1.Items.Add( HNames);
        }
```

The problem is that now I'm seeing the word 'Collection' within my comboBox after clicking the button, rather than the actual handling names.

**So my question is : How to use a list of variables within a comboBox ?**

Further info:  **I'm new to programming!** This is a windows form API, written in C#

Any help or guidance on this would be appreciated, if you could comment some keywords that I should Google that's helpful, if you understand the question & can produce a working answer that's also very helpful. I've been researching for hours, must be missing something

Comment: The core question (seeing the word 'Collection' ) was dealt with in comments on your previous question.

Comment: That's true, but after researching ItemRange, I got lost & confused. Thanks

Comment: You can ask in or under your old question. And why do you still use anonymous types?

Comment: I'm still using variables because I need the button click to load/display certain values depending on the handling name selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the collection to the combo box. You need to add each collection item to the combo box.

So:

```
foreach(var item in collection)
    Combobox.Items.add (item)
```

Comment: I slightly edited this to fit my API, but works well. Thanks

Comment: Why use a foreach loop to do This Instead of just a datasource?? That diesel not make Any sense

Comment: @Softwarehuset - The word  'diesel' does not make Any sense here either. Too much spell checker.

Comment: Damn freaking iPhone with Danish keyboard dictionary :) Diesel = Does

Comment: From what I can see,  the op is new to development and what he wants to see is his Combobox get populated when he clicks a button. I assume?  Yes,  I do agree with you, its better to set a binding. However, its not like this is going into enterprise production. The op should look into Xml serialization.  But I don't agree with setting bindings and not implementing a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead of working through the elements as you're currently doing, you can read the XML directly into a C# List object. This will be much easier to load from.

For example:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(myXmlFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyItemList));

        comboBox1.DataSource = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would an XmlSerializer trump an XDocument here? Makes no sense.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've added an example to illustrate it.

Comment: The XML (-data) is needed throughout the rest of the app, this is OK but does not answer the main question.

Answer (score 1):

YourCombobox.datasource = your list

YourComboxbox.displaymember = "yourPropertyName"

To get the Object afterwards you Can use YourComboxbox.selectedItem.DataboundItem and cast Tvis Object :)

Comment: Strange, this shows the first name only ..

Comment: This is because of displaymember only allows one property to be shown as a displaymember. Instead implement a property om your model class that combines multiple properties :)